# AngularJS + Jasmine test scripts failing fn is not function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm using Yeoman to create an angular project and have modules defined as:

```
angular.module('angularApp')<br />
.controller('LogOutCtrl', function ($scope) {//do stuff});
```

Test scripts via Yeoman are as follows:

```
describe('Controller: LogOutCtrl', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('angularApp', ['ui', 'appSettings']));

    var LogOutCtrl,
        scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
        scope = {};
        LogOutCtrl = $controller('LogOutCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

   it('should pass', function () {
        expect(2+2).toBe(4); //aka some test
   });
});
```

This is returning as an error via grunt/karma:

```
Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
```

I have looked at a few other ways of writing these as well:
[How do I test an AngularJS service with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013772/how-do-i-test-an-angularjs-service-with-jasmine)

Any help would be appreciated, as I am new to Angular and Jasmine testing. I believe this is probably an issue with Yeoman's templates for test scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow... same problem that I've already seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870410/emit-generates-an-error-when-using-testacular-karma/15873703#15873703 check my answer. May be its yeoman issue and we should post somewhere to change templates?

Comment: Issue has been resolved with an upgrade to Yeoman.

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with the templates that Yeoman was using. They have been resolved after an update from 1.0 beta.